# Вытянуть данные из строки

Tags: php, php7

Получаю строки данных погоды в следующем формате:

```
Date, Time, ABKtMSUNT000 [h], ABKtMWDIR012 [Deg.M], ABKtMWSPD012 [m/s], ABKtMTEMP002 [deg.C], ABKtMRAIN000 [mm/h] 190227, 2020, 9, 245.8, 2.886, 5.753, 0
```

Подскажите, как мне нужно вытянуть данные, чтобы их к массиву следующего вида:

```
[Date] => 190227
[Time] => 2020
[h] => 9
[Deg.M] => 245.8
[m/s] => 2.886
[deg.C] => 5.753
[mm/h] => 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Как по мне, этот вариант логичнее, если в строке встречается равное количество ключей и значений. Ну, в конце концов, велосипед тоже код :)

```
$string = 'Date, Time, ABKtMSUNT000 [h], ABKtMWDIR012 [Deg.M], ABKtMWSPD012 [m/s], 
ABKtMTEMP002 [deg.C], ABKtMRAIN000 [mm/h] 190227, 2020, 9, 245.8, 2.886, 5.753, 0';

$pr = preg_replace(['/(?<!,)(?=\h\d+)/', '/\w+\h\[([^]]+)\]/'], [',', '$1'], $string);

$ef = array_map('trim', explode(',', $pr));
$ex = array_chunk($ef, count($ef) / 2);

$data = array_combine($ex[0], $ex[1]);

print_r($data);
```

https://ideone.com/PNUAkF

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку входная строка имеет заданный формат, то я рекомендовал бы использовать регулярные выражения.
В php для регулярных выражений можно воспользоваться функцией [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php)

```php
    $str = '190227, 2020, 9, 245.8, 2.886, 5.753, 0';

    $pattern = '/([\S]*),\s([\S]*),\s([\S]*),\s([\S]*),\s([\S]*),\s([\S]*),\s([\S]*)/m';

    preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);

    $result =  [
        "Date" =>  intval($matches[1]),
        "Time" =>  intval($matches[2]),
        "h" => intval($matches[3]),
        "Deg.M" => floatval($matches[4]),
        "m/s" => floatval($matches[5]),
        "deg.C" => floatval($matches[6]),
        "mm/h" => floatval($matches[7])
    ];
```

Таким образом в `$result` окажется то что вам требуется.
`print_r($result)` выведет:

```
Array
(
    [Date] => 190227
    [Time] => 2020
    [h] => 9
    [Deg.M] => 245.8
    [m/s] => 2.886
    [deg.C] => 5.753
    [mm/h] => 0
)
```